# Get Private Func<T> Member with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with a definition of a private member like this:

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
private Func<String, String> MyFuncMember = (val) => val + " World! ";
```

and I'm trying to get the attribute that I put over it. Now, I have tried with **`Type.GetMembers()`**, **`Type.GetFields()`** and **`Type.GetMethods`** with the appropriate `BindingFlags` (`BindingFlags.NonPublic`) and I just cannot get that member. How can I retrieve it? Could it be a problem if the class where is defined is a **`sealed`** class?

Thanks in advance for you answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this as your binding flags:

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
```

Without the `BindingFlags.Instance` flag it won't be able to find your instance field.

In general when you use `Type.GetField` you need to set:

- one (or both) of `BindingFlags.Instance` and `BindingFlags.Static`

  **and**
- one (or both) of `BindingFlags.Public` and `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

The `|` operator combines the flags using a binary or operation, meaning that both flags are set.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof(YourType)
    .GetMember("MyFuncMember", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetCustomAttributes(true);
```